# How to structure a React + Express project?

Tags: reactjs, express, architecture

I'm creating my first full javascript app using React and Express. My main question is how to properly structure the app.
I checked some articles and started by separating the client and the server, something like:

```
root
|
--Client
|
--Server
|
(...)
```

But for instance, if I want to use Prettier and EsLint in my project for both the client and the server, I need to install the package on both apps. Although it makes sense to have the client app and the server app separated, it also seems redundant to have these common services duplicated for each one of them.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do so but I like to do it in the following way:

```
root
|
 -- Client (React)
     -- /node_modules
     -- package.json (React dependencies)
|
 -- Server (Express)
     -- Code related to server
|
 -- /node_modules 
 -- package.json (Node dependencies + common dependencies)
```

In this way, I don't have to install common dependencies multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more research on this and found some developers following this architecture. It also makes sense to me and it solves the problems I mentioned initially.